# How to add time to a dateTime in sqlite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, datetime

I have a table and in the table there is a date **creationDate**. which stores the timestamp like this

```
2013-12-23 10:07:42
2013-12-23 10:14:11
```

Actually I was using the mysql2sqlite.sh script to convert the database from mysql to sqlite. and while converting database it reduced the time 5:30 from the creationDate column. It might be some **GMT** problem. 

So now I want to update the timestamp and add 5 hours 30 minutes to each entry in the creationDate column.
I searched about it a lot but i didnt find the solution.
So how can i do it in sqlite ?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can use the [sqlite date functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) for simple math like this:

```
UPDATE tablename SET creationDate=DATETIME(creationDate, '+330 minutes');
```

Though usually it makes more sense to keep the database data in UTC and format to local timezone when displaying it.

Comment: First make sure the present values in `creationDate` column are valid datetime stamps (see `Time Strings` in the linked documentation).

Comment: Ok, but instead of hardcoding the value, Can I add the value from another table's column?

Comment: Check the latest version https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html