# Comparing fields of 2 table using Arel

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, arel

Let's say that I have 2 tables joining, table A and table B.

I want to compare 2 fields of these tables

```
table_A.project(Arel.star).join(table_B).where(table_A[:field_1].eq(table_B[:field_1]))
```

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you are trying to do please, rather than "some subtractions"?

Comment: I edit the question, is it clear? thank you in advance

Comment: It would still be more useful to pick a single specific thing and ask how to do that rather than give some examples of "the sort of thing you would like to do",

Comment: Also, which DBMS are you using - ie mysql, postgres, sqlite etc?

Comment: I am working in SQLite. I updated again my question. Lets start if I can use the equal operator.

Comment: What I see above is a `join` without `on`. I'm not sure this is right. And I fail to understand what exactly is the goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do a join and then compare between fields in different tables, it's best to use the format `tablename.columname`.  So,

```
table_A.project(Arel.star).join(table_B).where("table_a.field1 = table_b.field2")
```

You can use the standard comparison operators with these eg `<=, <, >, >= && <>` (<> means "not equal to" in sql)

EDIT: note that i have no idea what is produced by "table_A.project(Arel.star)", this is quite mysterious, so for all i know this might cause an error.

Comment: `table_A.project(Arel.star)` is merely Arel's counterpart of `SELECT * FROM table_a`. Following it are further AST modifications.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply :)! Now if I want to make a calculation inside the where: where("table_a.field1 + '1 year' = table_b.field2"), with some modifications, is it possible?

Comment: Looking at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21309204/how-to-add-time-to-a-datetime-in-sqlite and this http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html which i just googled in a few seconds (hint hint) it looks like you could do `.where("date(table_a.field1, "+1 years") = table_b.field2")`

Comment: thank u very much. Sorry if my question was obvious, but I am new in this.

Comment: No worries, it's not so much the obviousness (i don't think it's obvious at all really) as the google-ability of it.  But sometimes if you're new it's hard to know what to google for :)